# mysql loop with variable list

Tags: mysql

```
update [database].[table] 
set 
    [fieldalpha] = REPLACE(fieldAlpha,
        '/c/', '/c/[variable]')
where [fieldbravo] like "[variable]%";
```

So this code works and does what I need it to do. However I have a substantial number of variables that need to be applied to about 50k records. Is there a way to loop through this code with a list of replacements for [variable]?

Comment: variable from table or user entry..?

Comment: table entry if that works. The variables are static

Comment: Could use a stored procedure?

Comment: Stored Procedures don't support arrays from my understanding. I think based on further investigation I will have to use a scripting language and simply make the calls that way

Comment: Maybe SELECT the variables from the table and call the stored procedure on each one?

Comment: I wrote a script...thanks for your help.